# Filtrando valor id de url Google

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar o id especifico de urls google exemplo digamos que eu tenho essa url 
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-EMwJDMPmDIUG1UeHR6ZG9Rc0E&export=download o id desta url que e no exemplo  **0B-EMwJDMPmDIUG1UeHR6ZG9Rc0E**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os métodos [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php).

```
<?php

$url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-EMwJDMPmDIUG1UeHR6ZG9Rc0E&export=download";
$tmp = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($tmp, $parametros);

print($parametros["id"]);

?>
```

Exemplo: http://ideone.com/k337X8